# Is it possible to get glass armor in Xbox 360 skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've seen videos of people having it and it's really been irritating me because I can't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Once you reach level 36, Glass Armor begins appearing in dungeons, is sold by blacksmiths and merchants, and is worn by Thalmor patrols and soldiers . It can also be crafted if you have 70 Smithing and the Glass Smithing Perk.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Glass_Armor_(Skyrim)

Comment: @SkyrimFreak No problem. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking the tick below the vote buttons. We'll both get rep if you do.

Comment: @Studoku *"We'll both get rep if you do."* Sneaky you... +1

Comment: @Studoku this is my other Arquade account I'm sorry I haven't checked the check mark yet, I will most certainly do that when I get to my other device in a few days 